# Does $\csc(x)$ violate the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, asymptotics

I have been asked a question to explain as to why $f(x) = \csc(x)$ does not "break" the IVP between
$\left(\dfrac{-\pi}2,\dfrac{\pi}2\right)$.

Considering that the function is discontinuous, it already breaks the IVP. In addition, there is no $f(x)$ value that can be found between $f\left(\dfrac{\pi}2\right)$ and $f\left(-\dfrac{\pi}2\right)$ which makes the question even more confusing for me.

Comment: What do you mean there is no value that can be found between $f(\pi/2)$ and $f(-\pi/2)$?

Comment: $\csc(x)$ is not defined when $x=0\in\left(\frac{-\pi}2,\frac \pi 2\right)$

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. That's the point. $f(-\pi/2)=-1$ and $f(\pi/2)=1$, and yet there are no values of $\csc$ between $-1$ and $1$. This is correct.

Comment: They mean to say that a function “breaks” the IVT if it satisfies its hypotheses but not its conclusions. It is an unfortunate informal way of saying it, as it allows the incorrect interpretation of “it ‘breaks’ the hypotheses” (i.e., fails to satisfy the hypotheses). It would be better to say that $\csc(x)$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is *not* a counterexample to the IVT, and to ask why that is.

Answer (score 1):

As @J. W. Tanner pointed out, the Intermediate Value Theorem requires that $\csc(x)$ be *continuous* on the given interval, but $\csc(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$. Therefore, the Intermediate Value Theorem does not apply because one of its pre-conditions was not met.